# javascript unexpected token }

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, web

I have this block of code where I'm creating two link elements on a web page and adding a click event to them:

```
function createNewChat(){
     //alert("new chat fired");
     var roomName = document.getElementById("roomName").value
     if (roomName){
        resetErrorLog();           
        $('#createRoom').append('<p>would you like to password protect this room?</p>');
        $('#createRoom').append('<div><a href="#" onclick="newChatHelper("yes")"> yes </a></div>');
        $('#createRoom').append('<div><a href="#" onclick="newChatHelper("no")"> no </a></div>');
     }
     else {
     document.getElementById("errorlog").innerHTML = "<p>The room name input box seems to be empty</p>";
     }
  }
```

The DOM updates properly, but when I click the link I get an unexpected token } on line 2, which is an  tag. This block of code is much later in the file. The helper method isn't getting fired at all so I'm pretty sure that the problem is with this code. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Inspect the link and look what the HTML `onclick="newChatHelper("no")"` turns into (hint: look at the quotation marks).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`onclick="newChatHelper("yes")"` is a quoting issue in the HTML

You need to use `onclick="newChatHelper('yes')"` — notice the **single** quotes within the function call

But because you already have this in a single quote, you need to escape the inner single quotes, like this:

```
'<div><a href="#" onclick="newChatHelper(\'yes\')"> no </a></div>'
```

---

You could also consider not using the `onclick` attribute at all

```
$('#createRoom').append(
  $('<a href="#">yes</a>').click(function(event) {
    newChatHelper("yes");
    event.preventDefault();
  }).wrap('<div/>').parent()
);
```

**OR**

```
$('#createRoom').append(
  $('<div></div>').append(
    $('<a href="#">yes</a>').click(function(event) {
      newChatHelper("yes");
      event.preventDefault();
    })
  )
);
```

Comment: Yeah. I think it's deeper than that. The single quote will break the outer quotes

Comment: You might want show how to embed the single quotes into the string literal.

Comment: I'd suggest `\"` as a quick fix but it offends my sensibilities :)

Comment: @slebetman: It wouldn't help anyway, since ``\`` is not an escape character in HTML. I.e. `onclick="newChatHelper(\"yes\")"` would still produce the wrong result.

Comment: @FelixKling, I also provided a solution that can avoid the escaping entirely :)

Answer (score -6):

```
var roomName = document.getElementById("roomName").value
```

you may want to close this up with  a ;

```
var roomName = document.getElementById("roomName").value;
```

Comment: That's not the reason for the error. Semicolons are optional in most cases.

Answer (score -6):

```
 var roomName = document.getElementById("roomName").value
```

by 
     var roomName = document.getElementById("roomName").value;

Comment: That's not the reason for the error. Semicolons are optional in most cases.

Comment: That's not even a syntax error. It's just bad practice. But it's valid javascript